# How to do it switch ViewControllers with UISegmentedControl?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I have three arrays, for three cells of the control segment. I made one ViewController. And the array began to be scattered around cells, but I encountered a problem where it does not work for me to make the cell unit become the first. Now I want to remake.

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class PrognozSegmentViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

        var soccerString = [Soccer]()
        var basketString = [Basketball]()
        var tennisString = [Tennis]()

        var refresh : UIRefreshControl!

        @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
        @IBOutlet weak var segmentControl: UISegmentedControl!
        @IBAction func btnSegment(_ sender: Any) {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            var returnSport = 0
            switch (segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
            case 0 :

                returnSport = soccerString.count
                break
            case 1 :
                returnSport = basketString.count
                break
            case 2 :
                returnSport = tennisString.count
                break
            default :
                break
            }

            return returnSport
        }
```

Comment: Please share some code

Comment: probably you forgot to set tableView.delegate = self and tableView.dataSouce = self?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take out var returnSport from 'numberOfRowsInSection' method

```
var returnSport = 0
var soccerString = [Soccer]()
var basketString = [Basketball]()
var tennisString = [Tennis]()
var refresh : UIRefreshControl!
```

and change value type from Any to UISegmentedControl

```
@IBAction func btnSegment(_ sender: Any) {
   returnSport = sender.selectedSegmentIndex
   tableView.reloadData()
}
```

When you reload Data, you invoke numberOfRowsInSection method again and change returnSport variable